# How do you remove a listener from React Native's EventEmitter instance?

Tags: react-native, event-handling

There is `removeCurrentListener`, but no `removeListener` method.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js

`addListener` returns a `EmitterSubscription` instance that extends `EventSubscription` that has `remove` method.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventSubscription.js

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter();

const subscription = emitter.addListener('eventname', () => {});

subscription.remove(); // Removes the subscription
```

Comment: this.listener.remove() is not a function.

Comment: where is this file located? Noone didn't explain that

Comment: The only option now is to use `emitter.removeAllListeners('eventName')`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it does (unless I'm misunderstanding your question).

Here's how I do it:

```js
class Store extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(listenerKey) {
        super()
        this.listenerKey = listenerKey
    }

    emitChange() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.emit(this.listenerKey)
        }, 0)
    }

    addChangeListener(callback) {
        this.on(this.listenerKey, callback)
    }

    removeChangeListener(callback) {
        this.removeListener(this.listenerKey, callback)
    }
}
```