# React Native Warning: Receiving warning from the console

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react native and I am receiving this warning or error when I run my react native project.

```
           ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'EventEmitter.removeListener(\'change\', ...): Method has
           been deprecated. Please instead use `remove()` on the subscription returned by 
          `EventEmitter.addListener`.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886628/how-do-you-remove-a-listener-from-react-natives-eventemitter-instance) answer your question?

Answer (score 17):

Once you are sure that the deprecated use is happening in a dependency you cannot control, it is possible to silence these warnings. In your `App.js` or somewhere else add:

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";

LogBox.ignoreLogs(["EventEmitter.removeListener"]);
```

You have to use this with care, and probably remove it at some point in the future, because it will silence all warnings that contain `EventEmitter.removeListener` even ones that may be important to you.

Comment: This for me removed simple the warning in the actual react-native app not in console but resolved the situation my redux action was prevent to be handled.

Answer (score 11):

There is an upstream change, where in react-native@0.65.0 they deprecated the old api in favour of a more terse name, so `removeListener()` becomes `remove()`.

This means that any package you use that calls these will produce warnings as such, until they release new package versions to address this.

Your comment to Bharat Varma seems to suggest you're using https://github.com/react-native-community - they haven't released a new version in a long time, and there are [open Pull Requests](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/pull/244) targeting this same issue (which are going unaddressed at the moment).

Your best bet to get rid of it for now would be to use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to modify the node module with the PR fix linked above (just need to change removeListener to remove on the useDeviceOrientation hook they export), and use this until they merge fixes for this.

Comment: One year later, the package is not been updated yet. The best thing is to create your own hook for device orientation management.

Answer (score 11):

[According to official document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener), as of React Native Version 0.65+, removeListener is depreciated. You can use remove() now:

```
    useEffect(() => {
 const subscription = AppState.addEvenListener('change', ()=>{})
 return () => {
   subscription.remove()
 }
}, [])
```

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: How to call a callback after the subscription.remove() eg. how can I mimic  AppState.removeEvenListener('change', ()=>{console.log('removed listener')})?

Answer (score 5):

here’s how you remove the event listener.

`const susbcription = EventEmitter.addListener(‘change’,some_callback_function)`

to remove the listener. isntead of  EventEmitter.removeListener. u do this

`subscription.remove()`

Comment: No sir! when I import the useDeviceOrientation from the @react-native package I receive this error.!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to solve your problem while coding. Change in **library code** adding **patches** is not the great option.

```
var eventSubscription; 
    useEffect(() => {
        getDarkOrLightMode();
        eventSubscription =  Appearance.addChangeListener(onThemeChange);
        console.log('useEffect in DarkOrLight',eventSubscription);
        return () => {
          console.log("before   ---->  ",  eventSubscription );
          eventSubscription.remove();
          console.log("after   ---->  ",  eventSubscription );
        };
      }, []);
```