# React Native eventEmitter.removeListener deprecated error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting an deprecated error when using the follow code for removing event listener. When I try to use it anyway nothing happens. Can someone help me fix the code block so that I remove the event listen correctly. I am using this in a functional component

remove

```
eventEmitter.removeListener("PreparePaywallFinished", onPreparePaywallFinished);
```

add listener

```
eventEmitter.addListener("PreparePaywallFinished", onPreparePaywallFinished);
```

Here is same of the code I am working with

```
// raise paywall by event listener then clear listener after paywall is raised
const onPreparePaywallFinished = result => {
    if (result.success == true) {
      NativeModules.NamiPaywallManagerBridge.raisePaywall();
    } else {
      console.log('error is ' + result.errorMessage);
    }
    eventEmitter.addListener('PreparePaywallFinished', onPreparePaywallFinished)
      
  };

// create event listener on button press. also emit event
 const _handlePress = () => {
    console.log('pressed');
    const subscription =  eventEmitter.addListener('PreparePaywallFinished', onPreparePaywallFinished); //prettier-ignore
    NativeModules.NamiPaywallManagerBridge.preparePaywallForDisplay(true, 2); //prettier-ignore
  };

// button to be pressed 
return(
    <View>
        <Button title="press me" onPress={() => press()} />
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to Native documents, this has been deprecated and not used](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener). You can use `.remove()`

Comment: Yes I tried to use .remove() but was not sure how to. I have updated my question can you please look at it and provide example regarding the updated question

Comment: Use subscription.remove() as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901160/20201890